# Will changed username propagate to file permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts

I ran `lastb` and found login attemps that used my username. I doubt they would guess my password, but my 4-lowercase-letter dictionary username should probably be made more complex.

I'm going to add the first letter of my last name to it with

```
usermod -l login-name old-name
```

My user belongs to 3 groups other than itself. Will those change automatically? Will ownership of files not in the home directory reflect the new login name?

EDIT:
Also, will the user's group name change to match the new username?
Will the change take a long time if my user has many files?

Answer (score 2):

When using:

```
usermod -L login_name login
```

The name of the user will be changed from login to login_name. Nothing else is changed. In 
particular, the user's home directory name should probably be changed to reflect the new login 
name.

You can do that fast with

```
chown -R username /home/username
```

Changing permissions is usually quick, even with alot of files.

You can also fix the groups with sed.

```
sed -i ‘s/original_word/new_word/g’ /etc/group
```